# Use same array in two function PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know how I can take back my array in my second function : CreatejsonFile ? I try with global and GLOBALS but it doesn't work.

```
class Connection { //my class

public static function connect($request) { // function call database

$connect = oci_connect($user, $password, $connection_url3,'AL32UTF8'); 
$stmt = ociparse($connect,$request);
ociexecute($stmt,OCI_DEFAULT); 

$txt_job_aval = array();

while (ocifetch($stmt)){ 
array_push($txt_job_aval, ociresult($stmt,1)); 
}

public function CreatejsonFile(){

foreach($txt_job_aval as $valeur) 
    { 
    echo $valeur.'<br>'; 
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: `$this->txt_job_aval`

Comment: Don't make it global.... make it a property of the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't make it global.... make it a property of the class

```
class Connection { //my class

    protected $txt_job_aval;

    public function connect($request) { // function call database

        $connect = oci_connect($user, $password, $connection_url3,'AL32UTF8'); 
        $stmt = ociparse($connect,$request);
        ociexecute($stmt,OCI_DEFAULT); 

        $this->txt_job_aval = array();

        while (ocifetch($stmt)){ 
            array_push($this->txt_job_aval, ociresult($stmt,1)); 
        }
    }

    public function CreatejsonFile(){
        foreach($this->txt_job_aval as $valeur) { 
            echo $valeur.'<br>'; 
        } 
    }
}
```

and call as

```
$con = new Connection();
$con->connect($request);
$con->CreatejsonFile();
```

OR

```
class Connection { //my class

    protected static $txt_job_aval;

    public function connect($request) { // function call database

        $connect = oci_connect($user, $password, $connection_url3,'AL32UTF8'); 
        $stmt = ociparse($connect,$request);
        ociexecute($stmt,OCI_DEFAULT); 

        self::txt_job_aval = array();

        while (ocifetch($stmt)){ 
            array_push(self::txt_job_aval, ociresult($stmt,1)); 
        }
    }

    public static function CreatejsonFile(){
        foreach(self::txt_job_aval as $valeur) { 
            echo $valeur.'<br>'; 
        } 
    }
}
```

and call as

```
Connection::connect($request);
Connection::CreatejsonFile();
```

Comment: It's don't work. I don't find the mistake in the code

Comment: "It doesn't work" is __not__ a valid description for a problem.... explain what you mean by "It doesn't work". Does it show any errors? Does it crash your webserver? Does it display incorrect data? Does it set your house on fire?

Comment: `Using $this when not in object context `

Comment: Then don't make your connect call statically, make it against an instance; or make both methods static (and $txt_job_aval) and call everything statically

Comment: thank first solution work. Mistake is in the call. I do this :           Connection:: connect($request);                                                              and not                                                                                                $con = new Connection();
$con->connect($request);